# Ubuntu 20.10, Gnome shell becomes less 'snappy' after some time

Tags: gnome, 20.10

Ubuntu 20.10, Gnome shell becomes less 'snappy' after some time. I mean, i can see and feel that changing windodows (alt-tab) takes >100ms.
after killing 'gnome-shell' (process is automatically restarted)
system regains it's feeling of speed.
Any other remedy ?

Lenovo T14, i7-10510U (intel UHD), 48GB RAM, Ubuntu 20.10, windowing system X11 (everything up to date)

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug.

If you view the `top` command when it's slow, you'll see that gnome-shell has a memory leak and has gobbled up a ton of memory.

Under X11, you can easily restart gnome-shell with ALT-F2 (or ALT-FN-F2), then "r", then ENTER.

If at the login screen, you select your username, then click on the cogwheel icon, and select "Ubuntu under Wayland" you may not have this same problem.